# SQL Query for showing data based on Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a SQL query. My table as follows:-

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE
(
    Name VARCHAR(10), 
    NUM INT,
    PracticeName VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Tab 
VALUES ('A', 25, 'Test'), ('B', 30, 'Test'), ('C', 236, 'Test1'),
       ('D', 217, 'Test'), ('E', 19, 'Test1')
```

The query I am using is :

```
 SELECT 
     PracticeName,
     'Total:' + CAST(SUM(NUM) as varchar(10)) + ' ('+   
                STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Name + ':' + CAST(NUM as varchar(10))  
                       FROM @Tab  
                       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') +')'  
 FROM @Tab  
 GROUP BY PracticeName
```

The output I am getting is:

```
Test    Total:272 ( A:25, B:30, C:236, D:217, E:19)
Test1   Total:255 ( A:25, B:30, C:236, D:217, E:19)
```

I want the output as:-

```
Test      Total:272 ( A:25, B:30, D:217)
Test1     Total:255 (C:236, E:19)
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `where` clause on your `stuff()`

```
SELECT PracticeName,'Total:' + CAST(SUM(NUM) as varchar(10)) +' ('+   
 STUFF(  
  (  
  SELECT ', ' + s.Name +':'+ CAST(s.NUM as varchar(10))  
  FROM @Tab s 
  WHERE s.PracticeName = m.PracticeName
  FOR XML PATH('')  
  ), 1, 1, '') +')'  
 FROM @Tab m 
 GROUP BY PracticeName
```

Comment: `Explain solution, Code is not enough. Tell him/her what's wrong and why.`